# Нужна помощь с cout, не правильно выводит

Tags: c++

Сразу прощу прощение за заголовок , не знаю как это описать. Собственно есть код:

```
 system("cls"); // Очищение консоли
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        cout << "#";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == width - 1)
            {
                cout << "#";
                cout << "                    ";
            }
        }
      cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        cout << "#";
    }
```

Должен он делать квадрат, но почему-то он делает его , но последняя решетка выходит слишком далеко:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    cout << "#";
}

// а кто тут std::endl делать то будет?

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, как-то так...

```
system("cls"); // Очищение консоли
cout << "\n\n";
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    cout << "#";
cout << "\n";
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        if (j == 0 || j == width - 1)
            cout << "#";
        else
            cout << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    cout << "#";
}
cout << "\n";
```